# How to force Nuxt to not fetch data client side

Tags: nuxt.js

In my use-case I want to save backend resources by fetching content only in `nuxt generate`, not by each client on each navigate.

I see Nuxt saved all data to `dist/_nuxt/static/1635174977/body-type/suv/payload.js`, so clients can get all data from CDN. This payload.js was also prefetched on previous page when link become visible, but when user clicked the link it will not use already downloaded data from payload.js, but it will call (slow and expensive) backend to get the same data.

So it seems payload.js is used only for first page's hydratation, all other page's payload.js is prefetched but never used.

How to configure Nuxt to call backend only server-side (in static generation in CI), not on the client?

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  target: 'static',
  ...
  generate: {
    fallback: '404.html',
    exclude: [
      '/contact',
      '/login',
      '/privacy-policy',
      '/r/search-car-for-review',
      '/r/write-a-review',
      '/sign-up',
      '/terms-and-conditions',
    ]
  }
}
```

`pages/body-type/_slug.vue`

```js
fetch () {
  return this.$axios.$post('/graphql', {
    query: `
      ...
    `,
    variables: { slug: this.$route.params.slug }
  })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      this.bodyTypes = data.bodyTypes.entities
    })
},
fetchKey (getCounter) {
  return getCounter() + this.$route.params.slug
},
```

Comment: You can generate the project and access the actual data without any further requests to the API afterwards with the following: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#speeding-up-dynamic-route-generation-with-payload It only works with `asyncData` AFAIK.

Comment: As said here: https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/going-full-static#crazy-fast-static-applications

Comment: This it not use-case for routes payload, I does not want to fetch all content in generate. I want to fetch content in views.